# Calculating Catalan Numbers mod prime number

Tags: c++, c, 32-bit

The following is the problem description:

let `c[n]` be the catalan number for `n` and `p` be a large prime eg.`1000000007`

I need to calculate `c[n] % p` where `n` ranges from `{1,2,3,...,1000}`

The problem which I am having is that on a 32 bit machine you get overflow when you calculate catalan number for such large integer. I am familiar with modulo arithmetic. Also

```
(a.b) % p = ((a % p)(b % p)) % p
```

this formula helps me to get away with the overflow in numerator separately but I have no idea how to deal with denominators.

Comment: You don't have "denominators" in a finite field; instead, you need to compute the modular inverse.

Comment: No what I meant by "get away...separately" statement is that I could have done the calculation of the numerator alone but since there is a denominator also I can't directly apply modulo arithmetic to the numerator.

Comment: What are the maximum allowed sizes for `c(n)` and `p` and `n`? And by `c(n)` you mean the nth Catalan number right?

Comment: I am on a 32 bit machine so maximum allowed size is 4 byte int(2^32-1) and yes c[n] is the nth catalan number. You can take p to be such that it does not overflow int data type(Ex. 1000000007).

Comment: Can you update the link to original problem ?

Comment: yeah, here it is: http://www.codechef.com/APRIL12/problems/PANSTACK

Comment: You can calculate Catalan numbers without division. Don't confuse a mathematical formula with a computation algorithm. Mathematical formulas are usually chosen to look pretty, not to be computationally optimal.

Comment: @Ramond 
C(n) = (2n)!/(n+1)!n!
     = (2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)..(n+2)/n!
Now in the above formula, from the numerator we can take 2 as common from many terms and cancel the denominator terms. For ex. (2n-2)=2(n-1) and we can cancel (n-1) from denominators and numerator. But still we are left with many terms in the denominator and I am not sure that how to cancel them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a modulus of 1000000007, avoiding overflow with only 32-bit integers is cumbersome. But any decent C implementation provides 64-bit integers (and any decent C++ implementation does too), so that shouldn't be necessary.

Then to deal with the denominators, one possibility is, as KerrekSB said in his comment, to calculate the modular inverse of the denominators modulo the prime `p = 1000000007`. You can calculate the modular inverse with the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) or, equivalently, the continued fraction expansion of `k/p`. Then instead of dividing by `k` in the calculation, you multiply by its modular inverse.

Another option is to use Segner's recurrence relation for the Catalan numbers, which gives a calculation without divisions:

```
C(0) = 1
         n
C(n+1) = ∑ C(i)*C(n-i)
         0
```

Since you only need the Catalan numbers `C(k)` for `k <= 1000`, you can precalculate them, or quickly calculate them at program startup and store them in a lookup table.

---

If contrary to expectation no 64-bit integer type is available, you can calculate the modular product by splitting the factors into low and high 16 bits,

```
a = a1 + (a2 << 16)    // 0 <= a1, a2 < (1 << 16)
b = b1 + (b2 << 16)    // 0 <= b1, b2 < (1 << 16)
a*b = a1*b1 + (a1*b2 << 16) + (a2*b1 << 16) + (a2*b2 << 32)
```

To calculate `a*b (mod m)` with `m <= (1 << 31)`, reduce each of the four products modulo `m`,

```
p1 = (a1*b1) % m;
p2 = (a1*b2) % m;
p3 = (a2*b1) % m;
p4 = (a2*b2) % m;
```

and the simplest way to incorporate the shifts is

```
for(i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    p2 *= 2;
    if (p2 >= m) p2 -= m;
}
```

the same for `p3` and with 32 iterations for `p4`. Then

```
s = p1+p2;
if (s >= m) s -= m;
s += p3;
if (s >= m) s -= m;
s += p4;
if (s >= m) s -= m;
return s;
```

That way is not very fast, but for the few multiplications needed here, it's fast enough. A small speedup should be obtained by reducing the number of shifts; first calculate `(p4 << 16) % m`,

```
for(i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    p4 *= 2;
    if (p4 >= m) p4 -= m;
}
```

then all of `p2`, `p3` and the current value of `p4` need to be multiplied with 2<sup>16</sup> modulo `m`,

```
p4 += p3;
if (p4 >= m) p4 -= m;
p4 += p2;
if (p4 >= m) p4 -= m;
for(i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    p4 *= 2;
    if (p4 >= m) p4 -= m;
}
s = p4+p1;
if (s >= m) s -= m;
return s;
```

Answer (score 3):

what about if you store the results using dynamic programming and while populating the lookup table, you can use MODULO division at each step. It will take care of the overflow for the 1000 Catalans and also will be faster than BigDecimal/BigInteger.

### My solution:

```
public class Catalan {

private static long [] catalan= new long[1001];
private static final int MOD=1000000007;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    precalc();
    for (int i=1;i<=1000;i++){
        System.out.println("Catalan number for "+i+" is: "+catalan[i]);
    }
}

private static void precalc(){

    for (int i=0;i<=1000;i++){
        if (i==0 || i==1){
            catalan[i]=1;
        }
        else{
            long sum =0;long left, right;
            for (int k=1;k<=i;k++){
                left = catalan[k-1] % MOD;
                right= catalan[i-k] % MOD;
                sum =(sum+ (left * right)%MOD)%MOD;
            }
            catalan[i]=sum;
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a library for big integers? Try googling for it...

Comment: No that would not help. This is simplified version of a programming contest question and my problem solving logic is stuck here. I am sure that there will be some other way round as using big integer will be too time consuming.

Comment: Well if p is prime, and larger than the 32 bits representation, I don't think there is a way of using it in your program, unless using 64 bits.

Comment: we can safely assume that p does not create an overflow

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
C(n) = (2n)!/(n+1)!n!
     = (2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)..(n+2)/n!
*/
int p = 1000000007;

int gcd(int x, int y){
    while(y!=0){
        int wk = x % y;
        x = y;
        y = wk;
    }
    return x;
}

int catalanMod(n){
    long long c = 1LL;
    int i;
    int *list,*wk;
    //make array [(2n),(2n-1),(2n-2)..(n+2)]
    wk = list = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(n-1));
    for(i=n+2;i<=2*n;++i){
        *wk++ = i;
    }
    wk=list;
    //[(2n),(2n-1),(2n-2)..(n+2)] / [1,2,3,..n]
    //E.g C(10)=[13,17,19,4]
    for(i=2;i<=n;++i){
        int j,k,w;
        for(w=i,j=0;j<n-1;++j){
            while(1!=(k = gcd(wk[j], w))){
                wk[j] /= k;
                w /= k;
            }
            if(w == 1) break;
        }
    }
    wk=list;
    //Multiplication and modulo reduce 
    for(i=0;i<n-1;++i){
        if(wk[i]==1)continue;
        c = c * wk[i] % p;
    }
    free(list);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: mind adding some explanation of what's going on in your code?

Answer (score -1):

Simply, use the property, (a * b) % mod = (a % mod) * (b % mod)